# How can I merge two duplicates of an array?

Tags: matrices, algorithms, matlab

If I have an array `A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]`, is there any Matlab command that transforms that array to `A = [1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9]`?

Or do I need to use algorithms for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer.

$$A = [A;A](:)$$

Easy!

Comment: This is not valid Matlab code. It might work in Octave, but I'm not sure. `A=[A;A];` `A=A(:).'` (or @Nick's answer) would be valid.

Comment: You need to do this $$A = [A;A] \\ A (:) $$ in matlab.

Answer (score 3):

See the documentation for the [reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function. Here is how you can use it:

First, make a $2$-by-$n$ matrix which has both rows equal to $A$ with:

`[A;A]`

Then use the `reshape` function to "flatten" this matrix:

`reshape([A;A], 1, [])`

The output will be what your are looking for.